# Can a procedural macro be debugged as a function?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to debug a complex procedural macro in a library I am using.

Since I cannot use a debugger with macros and various macro expansion tools have proved useless here, I'm looking for an alternative.

Can a procedural macro be run like a function with proper debugging? I  imagine storing the resultant `proc_macro::TokenStream` in a variable.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/1.0.19/proc_macro2/index.html ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`proc-macro2` crate](https://crates.io/crates/proc-macro2) is a drop-in replacement for `proc_macro` except that it is available outside of macros - which makes it testable. Its types are all convertible to and from the `proc_macro` types and have identical methods.

The usual pattern for writing a nontrivial macro is to use `proc_macro` only for the entry point, and use `proc-macro2` for all of the real work:

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let output = transform_stream(TokenStream::from(input));
    proc_macro::TokenStream::from(output)
}

// A testable function!
fn transform_stream(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // actual work goes here
}
```

It's common to import items from `proc-macro2` so they can be used unqualified, and just used fully qualified names for `proc_macro`, since the only time you will use it is in the entry point. It's also usual to put the core components in a separate library crate, which does not have a dependency on `proc_macro`.

---

In tests, you can create a `TokenStream` from a string:

```
use std::str::FromStr;
let ts = TokenStream::from_str("fn foo() {}").unwrap();
```

Comment: Would something like https://pastebin.com/WpWCmtAk work?
How would I initiate a `TokenStream` to call `transform_stream` with?
(The actual macro I'm working on: https://docs.rs/vulkano-shaders/0.19.0/src/vulkano_shaders/lib.rs.html#320-365)

Comment: Hastebin alternative of the pastebin: https://hastebin.com/cawihocuxu.php (pastebin was being a bit weird)

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light you can just create TokenStream from a string: `TokenStream::from_str("fn foo() { }").unwrap();`