# Having trouble getting started with proc macros (why doesn't this work?)

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to follow this post to get my feet wet with proc macros ([Can a procedural macro be debugged as a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63272964/can-a-procedural-macro-be-debugged-as-a-function))

I came up with this to just to get a feel for how it all works:

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
use std::str::FromStr;
use syn;
use quote;

fn main() {
    let ts = TokenStream::from_str("fn foo() {}").unwrap();
    let _ts_str = ts.to_string();
    let parsed = syn::parse_macro_input!(ts);
}
```

But when I run in the Playground I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:10:18
    |
10  |     let parsed = syn::parse_macro_input!(ts);
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                  |
    |                  expected struct `proc_macro::TokenStream`, found struct `TokenStream2`
    |                  arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
note: function defined here
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.103/src/parse_macro_input.rs:138:8
    |
138 | pub fn parse<T: ParseMacroInput>(token_stream: TokenStream) -> Result<T> {
    |        ^^^^^
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::parse_macro_input` which comes from the expansion of the macro `syn::parse_macro_input` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:18
   |
10 |     let parsed = syn::parse_macro_input!(ts);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found struct `proc_macro::TokenStream`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::parse_macro_input` which comes from the expansion of the macro `syn::parse_macro_input` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I'm having trouble understanding what is going on, and could use some help. I've tried various typecasting but nothing seems to work.

I know as a Rust newbie I'm kinda jumping into the deep end of the pool here, but it is somewhat unavoidable. I'm running into little issues that I think will be barriers to getting Rust accepted for our application, and I'm trying to forge a path with as little friction as possible to convince our team (and myself) to move away from C/C++ in our embedded application. So I appreciate the help and patience here.

Comment: did you try it with `parse_macro_input!(ts as DeriveInput)`?

Comment: I guess I didn't think of this, since I was planning on creating a macro that wasn't a Derive macro. Would that change your recommendation to use DeriveInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` while the macro is expecting a `proc_macro::TokenStream`. Fortunately, they can be converted between each other with the basic `From`/`Into` traits.

---

You've not provided a type to parse into. You should have at least some idea of what kind of syntax you're expecting. Here you could use [`ItemFn`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.ItemFn.html) or more generally [`Item`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/enum.Item.html). Though if you're making a `#[derive()]` macro, you'd use [`DeriveInput`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.DeriveInput.html).

---

From the documentation on [`parse_macro_input`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/macro.parse_macro_input.html):

> This macro must be called from a function that returns `proc_macro::TokenStream`.

This is because the macro has error handling built-in and will early-exit with a stream containing a [`compile_error!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.compile_error.html) if the stream doesn't match the expected input type.

---

You may run into issues with trying this in a independent binary like you have here since `proc_macro` can only be used within a procedural macro invocation. You can replace the macro with [`parse2`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/fn.parse2.html) instead if that's what you want.

Here's a complete working example:

```
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
use std::str::FromStr;
use syn::ItemFn;

fn main() {
    let ts = TokenStream::from_str("fn foo() {}").unwrap();
    let parsed = syn::parse2::<ItemFn>(ts).unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", parsed);
}
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9742f003d564bd3a540e106a148ac5a5).